# How do you execute another file using a shell file?

Tags: shell

I am creating a program on Mac that uses a shell file to activate the program. I'm looking for a way to execute this file... 
~/Desktop/    Base Giants   0.1.0 BETA.app/Contents/Resources/loadBaseGiants.html 
Any way how to do that?

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 1):

OS X comes with the [`open` utility](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html), which is capable of launching applications, opening documents, and also URLs.

`~/'Desktop/Base Giants 0.1.0 BETA.app/Contents/Resources/loadBaseGiants.html'` is not an application [bundle], but an HTML file inside an application bundle.

To open this HTML file from a shell script, use:

```
open ~/'Desktop/Base Giants 0.1.0 BETA.app/Contents/Resources/loadBaseGiants.html'
```

<sup>Note that I've assumed that path component `Base Giants 0.1.0 BETA.app` does *not* start with a space.</sup>

If, by contrast, you wanted to open the application itself, use:

```
open -a ~/'Desktop/Base Giants 0.1.0 BETA.app'
```

Note the placement of the single quotes:

- The single quotes are needed to preserve path-internal spaces correctly.
- The `~/` prefix, by contrast, must be placed *outside* the single-quoted string in order for the `~` to be recognized as the home dir. (in order fo the shell to perform tilde expansion).